# Image size in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Images' sizes in `RecyclerView` are very different on a Phone and a Tablet. What is the cause and how to fix it?

How it looks on the phone Doogee X5 Pro (5 inches; 1280x720):
[image]

How it looks on the tablet (7 inches; 1024x600):
[image]

"Cards" have resolution 300x500

Comment: you can define the sizes in styles.xml for a phone and tablet differently and then reference those to resize. see if this helps - https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

Comment: @hello_world i want to know why the difference is so big. I think that on phone the image size is based on screen height, but on tablet is based on screed width

Comment: @hello_world can i proportionally stretch cards across the screen width?

Comment: its all relative, as the screen resolutions and densities change. a phone has higher pixel density(more pixels packed in a small area), therefore 300px is small, whereas on the tablet, the density is lower, pixels are spread out more, therefore 300px had more "lenght".

Comment: also, you could stretch the image, but that would probably make it less aesthetic. why dont you try using dp's (density independent pixels). check out the density independence section in the same above url